# Dangerous convenience feature of sample function in R

Tags: r

Please help me understand the reason for this convenience feature of the base `R` `sample` function before I submit a request to the `R` mailing list to modify.

```
set.seed(8675309)     
sample(x=c(5,6), size=1, replace=T)
#[1] 6
 
sample(x=5, size=1, replace=T)
#[1] 3
```

The first example returns the expected output. However, I was puzzled as to why 3 (instead of 5) was returned in the second example. I found this reasoning in the documentation.

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1,
> sampling via sample takes place from 1:x. Note that this convenience
> feature may lead to undesired behaviour when x is of varying length in
> calls such as sample(x). See the examples.

I don't consider this convenient. In fact, due to this feature, I spent over an hour trying to dissect an issue I thought was related to a completely different code chunk. And, I would automatically write the described convenience feature as follows.

```
sample(x=1:5, size=1, replace=T)
```

I'm hoping someone can provide a decent, statistically-savvy, reason for this feature that outweighs the potential issues that could arise (like my own) before I attempt to petition for a change to a function. Also, feel free to offer reasonable alternatives.

**Note:** I understand that one would typically not use this function to sample from a single value (what's the point, right?), but in this case, my function was generating a random sample of IDs that were stratified and then passed to the `sample` function, and these IDs were occasionally of length 1.

Comment: Yeah, I hate this feature too, precisely because it can easily contribute to a bug like you described. But I really doubt R Core will get rid of it, because some people do regularly make use of it.

Comment: @bschneidr, thanks for this feedback. I wonder, though, if the convenience of not having to type 1:5 really outweighs potentially issues like my own. I was sampling patient IDs, which could have very unintended consequences for our research had I not caught the oddities in my output. Ugh.

Comment: Completely agree. I fully support changing it, it’s just R Core is very conservative about changing things like this because they don’t want to break R packages and other code that rely on that feature.

Comment: It would take a book-length treatise to describe all the problems like this in `R`!  When you commit to using `R`, then -- whether you like it or not and whether you know it or not -- if you care about the quality of your work, you have also committed to constant, ongoing, testing and debugging to avoid problems like this.  Because your proposal would likely break a great deal of code, I strongly doubt it would go anywhere.

Comment: @whuber, you make a really good point. This could potentially be a cause for chaos in pre-existing `R` code and break a lot of `R` packages. I agree, then, with keeping as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunate, but it was that way even in Splus and people do use it, so it's unlikely to ever be changed. R Core is quite reluctant to break existing code that takes advantage of unambiguously documented behaviour.

You can always define your own version of `sample` that just leaves out the `length(x)==1` branch

```
safer_sample<-function(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL) 
{
        if (missing(size)) 
            size <- length(x)
        x[sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob)]
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative function! I also used this workaround, although I prefer yours as it's more explicit about what I want to do. `unlist(sample(as.list(5),1,replace=T))`.